# Can smart pointers be implicitly used as pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Are smart pointers considered as pointers? And thus can they implicitly used as pointers?

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    //...
    std::shared_ptr<AnotherClass> foo() { /*whatever*/ };
    void bar(AnotherClass* a) { /*whatever too*/ };
    //...
}
```

Then can I use `MyClass` the following way?

```
// m is an instance of MyClass
m.bar(m.foo());
```

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO! It would be a **terrible API**. Yes, you could easily implement it within `shared_ptr`, but just because you could doesn't mean you should.

Why is it such a bad idea? The plain-pointer-based interface of `bar` doesn't retain an instance of the shared pointer. If `bar` happens to store the raw pointer somewhere and then exit, there's nothing that guarantees that the pointer it had stored won't become dangling in the future. The only way to guarantee that would be to retain an instance of the shared pointer, not the raw pointer (that's the whole point of `shared_ptr`!).

It gets worse: the following code is undefined behavior if `foo()` returns a pointer instance that had only one reference when `foo()` returned (e.g. if `foo` is a simple factory of new objects):

```
AnotherClass *ptr = m.foo().get();
// The shared_ptr instance returned by foo() is destroyed at this point
m.bar(ptr); // undefined behavior: ptr is likely a dangling pointer here
```

Here are the options; consider those listed earlier first before considering their successors.

- If `bar(AnotherClass *)` is an external API, then you need to wrap it in a safe way, i.e. the code that would have called `Original::bar` should be calling `MyWrapped::bar`, and the wrapper should do whatever lifetime management is necessary. Suppose that there is `startUsing(AnotherClass *)` and `finishUsing(AnotherClass *)`, and the code expects the pointer to remain valid between `startUsing` and `finishUsing`. Your wrapper would be:

  ```
  class WithUsing {
    std::unique_ptr<AnotherClass> owner; /* or shared_ptr if the ownership is shared */
    std::shared_ptr<User> user;
  public:
    WithUsing(std::unique_ptr<AnotherClass> owner, std::Shared_ptr<User> user) :
      owner(std::move(owner)), user(std::move(user)) {
      user.startUsing(owner.get());
    }
    void bar() const {
      user.bar(owner.get());
    }
    ~WithUsing() {
      user.finishUsing(owner.get());
    }
  };
  ```

  You would then use `WithUsing` as a handle to the `User` object, and any uses would be done through that handle, ensuring the existence of the object.
- If `AnotherClass` is copyable and is very cheap to copy (e.g. it consists of a pointer or two), then pass it by value:

  ```
  void bar(AnotherClass)
  ```
- If the implementation of `bar` doesn't need to change the value, it can be *defined* to take a const-value (the declaration can be without the `const` as it doesn't matter there):

  ```
  void bar(const AnotherClass a) { ... }
  ```
- If `bar` doesn't store a pointer, then don't pass it a pointer: pass a const reference by default, or a non-const reference if necessary.

  ```
  void bar(const AnotherClass &a);
  void bar_modifies(AnotherClass &a);
  ```
- If it makes sense to invoke `bar` with "no object" (a.k.a. "null"), then:

  1. If passing `AnotherClass` by value is OK, then use `std::optional`:

     ```
     void bar(std::optional<AnotherClass> a);
     ```
  2. Otherwise, if `AnotherClass` takes ownership, passing `unique_ptr` works fine since it can be null.
  3. Otherwise, passing `shared_ptr` works fine since it can be null.
- If `foo()` creates a new object (vs. returning an object that exists already), it should be returning `unique_ptr` anyway, *not* a `shared_ptr`. Factory functions should be returning unique pointers: that's idiomatic C++. Doing otherwise is confusing, since returning a `shared_ptr` **is meant to express existing shared ownership**.

  ```
  std::unique_ptr<AnotherClass> foo();
  ```
- If `bar` should take ownership of the value, then it should be accepting a unique pointer - that's the idiom for "I'm taking over managing the lifetime of that object":

  ```
  void bar(std::unique_ptr<const AnotherClass> a);
  void bar_modifies(std::unique_ptr<AnotherClass> a);
  ```
- If `bar` should retain shared ownership, then it should be taking `shared_ptr`, and you will be immediately converting the `unique_ptr` returned from `foo()` to a shared one:

  ```
  struct MyClass {
    std::unique_ptr<AnotherClass> foo();
    void bar(std::shared_ptr<const AnotherClass> a);
    void bar_modifies(std::shared_ptr<AnotherClass> a);
  };

  void test() {
    MyClass m;
    std::shared_ptr<AnotherClass> p{foo()};
    m.bar(p);
  }
  ```

`shared_ptr(const Type)` and `shared_ptr(Type)` will share the ownership,
they provide a constant view and a modifiable view of the object, respectively. `shared_ptr<Foo>` is also convertible to `shared_ptr<const Foo>` (but not the other way round, you'd use `const_pointer_cast` for that (with caution). You should always default to accessing objects as constants, and only working with non-constant types when there's an explicit need for it.

If a method doesn't modify something, make it self-document that fact by having it accept a reference/pointer to `const something` instead.

Answer (score 4):

No they can't be used interchangable. You would get a compiler error in your example. But you can always get the raw pointer by `shared_ptr::get()`.

Answer (score 2):

[Smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) are used to make sure that an object is deleted if it is no longer used (referenced).

Smart pointer are there to manage lifetime of the pointer they own/share.

You can think of a wrapper that has a pointer inside. So the answer is no. However you can access to the pointer they own via `get()` method.

Please note that it is not so difficult to make dangling pointers if you use `get` method, so if you use it be extra cautious.